# Holden Commodore not moving

Tags: engine, noise

I own a petrol powered Holden Commodore car 1998 model and it worked fine till last week. Suddenly it stopped moving freely.

When I press the accelerator up to 30% it makes noise but doesn't move. If I press the accelerator up to 50% it's making as much noise as when the car is accelerated to 50% but slowing moving at a speed of 10kph and I need to forcefully accelerate like this everyday.

I also have to cross a hill which my car is unable to cross. Though I am giving full gas, the car is unable to get over it. However, if I accelerate on a flat road for 500 meters ahead of time it can climb up.

This car is in auto transmission, it just has a button to change gear position from N/P/D/R.

I don't know what's the problem behind this. Can anybody help me out how to fix this issue?

Taking to a car mechanic in Australia is worse than purchasing another car.

Comment: Maybe check the transmission fluid levels? It sounds like clutch isnt engaging with the engine.

Comment: @MeltingDog - Thanks mate, many said same. Have to check it today.

Comment: Torque converter problem, it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

The Holden Commodore is the same as the Opel Omega and Chevy Lumina. Most of them that year used the 4L60E automatic I believe.

Check the following:

Emergency brake is off (if you have one)

Transmission fluid level - this is an automatic by description so no clutch to check

Verify it shifts - when you hit the button for neutral, can you push the car? When in Reverse, will it travel in Reverse at normal speeds?

You may be out of fluid and then running it even more may have further damaged the transmission.

Basically, check the fluid. If low or empty, re-fill and have a transmission shop take a look at it. By 1998 OBDII should have been in effect and they may be able to pull a code history from the transmission control module.

Answer (score 0):

I'd find a specialist on Aussie automatics. Hunt through your friends to find who has had quality gearbox work done on their autos. If any go racing or have performance cars, ask their advice, too.

Commodore bits shouldn't be hard to find, but replacing a whole gearbox will be expensive. Hopefully it will be something easy like an arm inside the torque converter.